# python multiprocessing AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'has'

Tags: python-3.x, multiprocessing, threadpool

when I tried to use `multiprocessing` module, `Python` generated the following error,

```
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'has'
```

the code using `multiprocessing` is,

```
import multiprocessing
p = multiprocessing.Pool(max_processes)
p.map(worker_function, input_data) # trigger the error
```

it traces to `Pool class`,

```
def map(self, func, iterable, chunksize=None):
    '''
    Apply `func` to each element in `iterable`, collecting the results
    in a list that is returned.
    '''
    return self._map_async(func, iterable, mapstar, chunksize).get() # error traced to here
```

finally traced to (still in `class Pool`),

```
def get(self, timeout=None):
    self.wait(timeout)
    if not self.ready():
        raise TimeoutError
    if self._success:
        return self._value
    else:
        raise self._value # error pointes to here
```

`input_data` is an instance of a class that inherits `dict`.
I am new to `multiprocessing`, so wondering what's happening here?

Comment: you need to show the entire traceback message, I do not see how `self._value` will raise the error `str has no attribute 'has'`

Comment: Shot in the dark but first thought that comes to mind is - do you have a local file names the same as something Python is importing? That's bitten me before and can produce seemingly bizarre results like this IIRC.